# How to get all the Launchpad bugs using a given tag using launchpadlib?

Tags: launchpadlib

Is there a way to retrieve all the bugs that have been tagged using a given tag using launchpadlib?

I'm looking at something like:

```
launchpad.bugs(tag='bitesize')
```

Comment: Only bugID is [supported](https://launchpad.net/+apidoc/devel.html#bugs) I think. Would be interesting to know about tag also.